# How to clean up my messed up savegames list?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

[image: Too many savegames...]

After a few crashes I ended up with multiple and duplicate savegames for my ironman run. Clicking the delete game button removes the savefile for *all* identical save, but not the list entry, and I have to restore a backup of that file in order to be able to play that savefile again at all. How to clean up this mess? Manually deleting the respective savefiles also seems to fail since apparently `profile.bin` contains some information on the savegames as well, or is Steam's cloud interfering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the following things must have fixed this:

- A recent update
- My deleting the entire savegames folder before *and* after starting Steam